# `'jQuery.timer.global' is null or not an object`

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools, ie8-browser-mode

I get the following error in IE8 on one of my computers, but not the other:

> 'jQuery.timer.global' is null or not an object

The error is coming from the file `jquery.timers.js` in this section (where `var global` is defined):

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie)
    jQuery(window).one("unload", function() {
        var global = jQuery.timer.global;
        for ( var label in global ) {
            var els = global[label], i = els.length;
            while ( --i )
                jQuery.timer.remove(els[i], label);
        }
    });
```

I have no idea what this block of code is for or what it does, but it is clearly the source of the problem, since the bug that originally led me here had to do with the timing of a mouse event that worked on one computer but not the one where I discovered this JS error.

The only difference that I can think of between the computers is that the one where it works is actually running IE10 but is set to IE8 document/standards mode. I've found the IE document modes to be reliable in the past, but maybe that's the issue here?

What does this error mean and why does it show up inconsistently?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the error is showing up in IE8.

Your plugin appears to be v1.0 and comes from the old JQuery plugin repository:

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/node/3656/release

And the author put in a fix in a later release of this plugin for `JQuery.timer.global` but doesn't say what was fixed.

The plugin repository has been shut down, but you can download the latest version (1.2) of this plugin (still quite old - 2009) here and give it a try:

https://github.com/patryk/jquery.timers/blob/master/jquery.timers.js